# React Calendar gives Error on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, react-webpart

I am new to SP dev fx components and have used `react-calendar` linked [react-calendar](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-calendar). I works fine on Chrome, Firefox but gives error

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'from'
```

on Internet Explorer. I have seen that it is because of Polyfill not supported with IE11. I tried to add

```
import 'core-js/modules/es6.promise'
import 'whatwg-fetch'

import 'core-js/modules/es6.array.iterator.js'
import 'core-js/modules/es6.array.from.js'

import 'es6-map/implement'
```

but got this error now

```
in Uncontrolled(Component)in ForwardRefin divin divin divin Unknownin Unknown
```

I am very new to this and not sure where else to look. Can anyone suggest me what wrong has happened.

Regards,
Saghir

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this exact same issue and symptoms as described above.  After walking throught the IE11 stack trace (blech!) and debugging through minified code, I notice that the topmost error was coming from e.createAssignPolyfill method in sp-pages-assembly.js.

This one-liner at the entrypoint of my spfx webpart is what finally worked:

import 'core-js/stable/object/assign'

You would think just drop "polyfill-ie11" or "corejs/stable" would fix everything, but then you run into the "invariant violation: Minified React error".  In this case, I needed exactly one polyfill, no more, no less.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Install polyfill using the command below.

```
npm install --save @pnp/polyfill-ie11
```

And then add the below imports to your main .ts file.

```
import "@pnp/polyfill-ie11";
```

If it still not works, try to add the below imports.

```
import "core-js/es6/array";
import "es6-map/implement";
import "core-js/modules/es6.array.find";
```

Comment: after importing @pnp/polyfill-ie11 i get `Invariant Violation: Minified React error#31`  `in Unknownin Unknownin Unknownin divin Unknownin formin Unknownin divin asidein Unknownin Unknownin divin Unknownin divin divin Unknownin divin divin Unknownin CustomizedPageLayoutScrollRegionin articlein Unknownin Unknownin Unknownin Unknownin Unknownin Unknownin Unknownin Unknownin Unknownin sectionin divin divin Unknownin Styledundefinedin Unknownin Unknownin Unknownin Unknownin Unknown`

Comment: after above error i added the other 3 imports but same error. I removed `@pnp/polyfill-ie11` from import keeping the other 3 i go t this `in Uncontrolled(Component)in ForwardRefin divin divin divin Unknownin Unknown`